# How to get no. of rows returned in a recordset variable in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class Mymodel extends CI_Model
{

   public function getData($passwd,$email)
   {
     //$flag=0;


      $u->where('username', $email);
      $u->where('password', $passwd);
     $total = $u->count();
     echo $total;

}
}
```

I want to display total no. of rows returned by `$u->count()` but i am getting following error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: u
>
> Filename: models/mymodel.php
>
> Line Number: 10

Comment: As the error says, there is no variable named `$u` defined.

Comment: where have you set your variable `$u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return count

```
 public function getData($passwd, $email)
 { 
     //$flag=0;
     $this->db->where('username', $email);
     $this->db->where('password', $passwd);
     $total = $this->db->count_all_results('table_name');
     return $total;
 }
```

the above method returns the count, you can call it simply

```
echo $this->mymodel->getData($passwd, $email);
```

from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because there is no variable `$u` in the scope of that class. You will need to pass it into the function

`public function getData($passwd, $email, $u)`

There are several ways this can be achieved but that is the easiest solution.